# java sending mail automatically

Tags: java, email, sendmail

I wanted the mail to be sent automatically at a specific time. I am able to send a mail but I can't make it to be done automatically . Can anyone please tell me how to send automatically? These below are my codes for sending a mail:

```
public class SendEmail {

    String d_email = "sofien.fkih@gmail.com",
            d_password = "",
            d_host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            d_port = "465",
            m_to = "sofien.fkih@gmail.com",
            m_subject = "Testing",
            m_text = "Hey, this is the testing email.";

    // Those are the values that have the email information
    public void send(String from, String pass, String host, String port, String to, String subject, String text) {

        Properties props = new Properties();

        // Read properties file.

        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();

        try {
            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setText(text);
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(d_email, d_password);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want a Java solution (schedule that email task to be executed from your code) or do you want an external solution that will run your application at a specific time?

Answer (score 4):

Check out `java.util.Timer` and if it is not enough for you read about [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) - the pure java cron compatible scheduler.

Comment: Quartz or the OS, the two options you want to use--quite honestly a scheduled task (Cron on Linux) is what you're after. If you have an web system Quartz is great.

Answer (score 1):

Quartz seems better option.This [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/) might help you to set up quartz.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public class SendEmail extends TimerTask{

public static void main(String[] args){
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new SendEmail(), 0, 9000); //send email every 9 seconds
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Your email syntax here
}
```

}